# How to implement is_empty() in PHP?

Tags: php

The empty() native in PHP will fail if the string is "0" or something like that.

So how to implement the exact is_empty() function in PHP?

Comment: The function does not fail, it works according to its specification.

Comment: What exactly do you understand by an empty value? What values are empty in your opinion?

Comment: What other cases fall under 'something like that'

Comment: `empty("0")` is not `false`, because its obviously a non-empty string. A reimplementation would break everyones expectations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
function is_empty(&$val) {
  return empty($val) && $val !== "0";
}
```

`&$val` is needed, so you don’t get a warning on undefined variables.

if you only want to check if a variable is set (regardless of its value) you should use PHP’s [`isset`](http://php.net/isset)

Comment: You need strict type checking, don't you? It should be 
&& $val !== "0";

Otherwise PHP can convert false and "" to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use isset if you are trying to check if that variable is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [type comparison table](http://us.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in the PHP manual for the exact behaviour of empty(), isset(), is_null() etc. You'll probably find what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this one:

```
/**
 * Checks if a scalar value is FALSE, without content or only full of
 * whitespaces.
 * For non-scalar values will evaluate if value is empty().
 *
 * @param   mixed   $v  to test
 * @return  bool    if $v is blank
 */
function is_blank (&$v)
{
    return !isset($v) || (is_scalar($v) ? (trim($v) === '') : empty($v));
}
```

See http://3960.org/sandbox/empty.php for its behavior. Essentially all values will be returned the same as with empty(), but for strings and numbers evaluating to '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, check for the error case described above.  If you run into it, return the result you want.  If not, call empty() and return that result.

Answer (score 0):

I always add to my codebase

```
function is_blank($value) {
    return empty($value) && !is_numeric($value);
}
```

and use it instead of empty(). It solves the issue of keeping zeros (int, float or string) as non-empty.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#103756 which was added May 2011.